# How to make custom paperclip processors to resize image size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I am using paperclip to resize images in my rails app, like this

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>" }
```

This gives me a image of size 60kb, I would like to use paperclip processor to make some custom methods to reduce the size of image, how can I do that and how can I call the imagemagick functions directly from these process?

thanks

Comment: + 1  for how can I call the imagemagick functions directly from these process?

Comment: @saurabh - use :convert_options, eg
**has_attached_file :photo, :convert_options => {:name_of_style => "imagemagick stuff"}**

Answer (score -1):

In my picture model:

```
  has_attached_file :picture,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
                    :styles => { :original => "319x228#", :thumb => "100x60#" },
                    :path => "article/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :bucket => YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazon_s3.yml")[RAILS_ENV]["bucket_name"]
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/png']
```